Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'leaflet.animatedmarker'
I ran the npm install -S leaflet.animatedmarker command.
My package.json file contains "leaflet.animatedmarker": "^1.0.0". However I couldn't run the project. I got Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'leaflet.animatedmarker' error. My code block is
import L from "leaflet";
import "leaflet-animatedmarker";

const animatedMarker = L.animatedMarker([
               ....
            ], {
                .... 
            });

How can I fix the problem?

I solved problem. Solution is import like;
import "leaflet.animatedmarker/src/AnimatedMarker";
